# Find and get the value in vba

Tags: vba

I am able to update the values in cells but I want to first check if the cell is already updated.

I used the below code to get the value but it is showing an error.

`String = .Offset(0, 6).Cells.Value`

Complete code

```
With ws1
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    iRow1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    With .Range("J1:J" & iRow1)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Str
        .Offset(0, 2).Cells.Value = VBA.Environ("Username")
        .Offset(0, 4).Cells.Value = VBA.Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm AM/PM ")
        .Offset(0, 6).Cells.Value = Comments
    End With

    .AutoFilterMode = False

End With
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about "updating the values"? And: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I am getting below error. Run-time error 13. Type mismatch. Please confirm if there is no mistake in below code. String1 = .Offset(0, 6).Cells.Value. I want to update the data in cells

Comment: You first fill your cell with `Comments`, where does it come from? which datatype is `Comments`?